# Get a JSONObject of a JSONArray with Value by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi assume that I have a JSON like this:

```
var myJson = [{"id":"111","name":"aaa","surname":"bbb"},
     {"id":"222","name":"ccc","surname":"ddd"}]
```

is there any function to get one of jsonobject with a value of jsonobject?
I mean maybe I know that id is 111 how can get the jsonobject with id=111, I don't want to get it with loop I mean is there just function to do it with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Json array as below

```
var myJson = { "idarray":["111","222"],
"dataarray":{ "111":{"name":"aaa","surname":"bbb"},"222":{"name":"ccc","surname":"ddd"}}
};
```

Now you can access it as below:

> myJson.dataarray[myJson.idarray[0]].name   //  ==> "aaa"
>
> or directly by
>
> myJson.dataarray[111].name   //  ==> "aaa"

Answer (score 1):

You have an array with two objects in it.  To find which array element (if any) has an object with id=="111", you would have to search the array and look at each object to find which one has the desired object in it.

When using a plain array, there is no magic way to find something in it without looping through the array.  If keys are unique and order is not important, you can use an object instead of an array to directly index into a given object without searching for it.  But given the data structure you or some piece of code has to loop through the array.

```
function findId(target, array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].id == target) {
            return(i);
        }
    }
    return(-1);
}
```

Comment: Which is exactly what he's trying to avoid. He does *not* want to loop over his array. Well, the obvious answer here is: nope. There is no way to do it unless you loop through the array. **That's what loops are there for!!**

Comment: @Joseph Siber - that's what I'm telling him.  This is the only way to find something in a plain array.

Comment: Roger that. Sorry for intruding ;)

Comment: I thougt maybe there is a func like this   $.JSONField("myJson[id=111]") , if there is, it would be very useful :)

Comment: I just wrote it for you.  Copy it into your code and call it whenever you need it.